# Getting stack limit exceeded when working with nested JSON

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, socket.io

I am working with League Of Legends API and trying to get a value from a JSON.

The JSON has a structure of this.

---

```
{
    "data":
          {
             "Aatrox":
                      {
                        "id":266,
                        "spells": [{
                                    "cooldown": [
                                                 16,
                                                 15,
                                                 14,
                                                 13,
                                                 12
                                                ]
                                  }]

                       }
           }
 }
```

I am using

```
    function walk(json) {
        for (var key in json) {
            if (json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                var val = json[key];
                if(val.hasOwnProperty('cooldown')){
                    console.log(val);
                }
                walk(val);
            }
        }
    }
    walk(json);
```

It works for smaller JSONS, but the JSON I am provided with gives stack limit exceeded error.

I am trying to get the cool downs values, Aatrox is the champions name, I want to run this recursively to get it from 130 champs.

I am new to this and would like some suggestions, Thanks!

Comment: Should the json you've provided in the question demonstrate the error you are getting?

Comment: `If(Val` is wrong and needs to be `if(val`. It also seems you don't have a base case to escape the recursion.

Comment: That was just my autocorrect for some reason

Comment: Won't the code escape when the object has no more properties?

Comment: @Djinnes After fixing your syntax and other errors, I'm not getting any errors.

Comment: True it does run for this smaller part of JSON, repeat aatrox structure 130 times as that is the full JSON I am using. This is here the limit is exceeded

Comment: I tried that, for over 200 times, it works fine.